# How to filter a NumPy array using value of another NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one NumPy array like this:

```
type = array(["A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"])
```

I want to use this array to filter another array like this:

```
data = array([5,4,5],
             [0,4,3],
             [2,1,6],
             [6,7,9],
             [0,1,4],
             [7,9,8],
             [1,4,9])
```

I want to be able to filter the data by type, such that:

```
typeA = array([5,4,5],[2,1,6],[7,9,8],[1,4,9])
typeB = array([0,4,3],[6,7,9],[0,1,4])
```

Any idea how should I implement it? Since the first array is not boolean, I'm having a lot of trouble to figure out the solution

Comment: And what does `type = array([[A],[B],[A],[B],[B],[A],[A])` look like exactly? What is `.dtype`? What is `.shape`?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, 'type = np.array(["A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"])', I'll correct that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define your arrays:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> data = array(([5,4,5], [0,4,3], [2,1,6], [6,7,9], [0,1,4], [7,9,8], [1,4,9]))
>>> type_ = array(["A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"])
```

Now, let's find your typeA:

```
>>> A = data[type_=="A"]
>>> A
array([[5, 4, 5],
       [2, 1, 6],
       [7, 9, 8],
       [1, 4, 9]])
```

And your typeB:

```
>>> B = data[type_=="B"]
>>> B
array([[0, 4, 3],
       [6, 7, 9],
       [0, 1, 4]])
```

Here, `type_=="A"` or `type_=="A"` are boolean arrays.  We use them to select the elements from `data` that we want.

For more on indexing with boolean or “mask” arrays, see the [NumPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Lastly, `type` is a python builtin and it is best practices not to overwrite it.  So, we used `type_` here instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

type_ = np.array(['A','B','A','B','B','A','A'])
data = np.array([[5,4,5],
                 [0,4,3],
                 [2,1,6],
                 [6,7,9],
                 [0,1,4],
                 [7,9,8],
                 [1,4,9]])

from collections import defaultdict
type_splitted = defaultdict(list)
for type_i, data_i in zip(type_, data):
    type_splitted[type_i].append(data_i)
typeA = np.asarray(type_splitted['A'])
typeB = np.asarray(type_splitted['B'])
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my original question, the type array should be `type = np.array(["A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"])` instead. how should i solve this question in that case?